# How mariadb/mysql events works actually, in case of ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY ? and What is the use of ENDS? Does it completely disable event?

Tags: mysql, events, stored-procedures, triggers, mariadb

```
  CREATE EVENT test_event5
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY  
  STARTS  TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE)+ INTERVAL 1 DAY 
  ENDS  TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE)+ INTERVAL 1 DAY+ INTERVAL 1 HOUR
  ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
  DO  --Any query here--
```

I have written this event but it I have a little confusion on STARTS date? What will be next STARTS and ENDS date after executing this.  Suppose today is 2022-Jan-05, as per my code its STARTS and ENDS date will be 2022-Jan-06 which is next day. What will be the start date at 2022-Jan-06 ? Will it be change to 2022-Jan-07?

As per my understanding STARTS date be 2022-Jan-07 in the next day.
What is the use of ENDS ?

Need expert opinion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a very good documentation about the event scheduler on the MariaDB website: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/event-scheduler/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`STARTS` defines when the event will begin to be active and `ENDS` defines when the event ceases to execute. *Both do not move or change, they are static values*.

Your event will never execute outside this defined time window.

You define a time window during which your event is able to execute in intervals defined in `ON SCHEDULE EVERY`, given that `ON COMPLETION PRESERVE` is defined otherwise it will only execute once and then dropped.

Comment: Thanks for straight forward answer. I Understood.